# What is the meaning of the number under the "up" arrow?

Tags: support

What is the meaning of the number under the arrow "rise to the top"?

[image]

Comment: @oded Am I glancing over it, or does that dupe not actually mention the UI element key to this question?

Comment: @Bart - I may have been a bit hasty in my choice of duplicate. However, this is covered by the new about page and is so basic to how the site works and its conventions, that I can't help but see this question as one lacking in minimum research effort.

Comment: @Oded Sure, no argument there. (And since you're a mod now I wouldn't dare anyway. ;) )

Comment: @Bart - **Always** question authority.

Comment: P.s. [This is the About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) Oded was referring to @automatix. Perhaps worth a look.

Comment: The about page does not really give an answer to my question. But you are right -- I should look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That indicates the current score of the particular post. Or the number of upvotes it received minus the number of downvotes.